# Can you override the body deserialization web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

When I attempt to override serialization settings for a controller they are used for creating the response but ignored when parsing the body.

I need to override the json serialization settings for each requests in WebAPI. I am trying to change the serialization settings based on the route in use. Example: if it is a V1 api use SerializationSettingsA, if it is a V2 api use SerializationSettingsB.

I have tried multiple approaches including overriding the IContentNegotiator and IHttpControllerActivator hoping to set the serialization settings for the context but in all case it does not work. The behavior I am seeing is that the override serialization settings are used when crating the response body but not when parsing the request. Is there some other settings that need overriding for changing how the request body is parsed.

```
class PerControllerConfigActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private static readonly DefaultHttpControllerActivator Default = new DefaultHttpControllerActivator();

    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        controllerDescriptor.Configuration = HttpConfigurationFactory.CreateDefaultConfiguration();
        controllerDescriptor.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Insert(0,
            new VersionedPropertyConverter(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri));

        var result = Default.Create(request, controllerDescriptor, controllerType);
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
        configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        configuration.Formatters.Clear();
        configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new PerControllerConfigActivator());
        app.UseWebApi(configuration);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing some ideas from [here](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/september/custom-input-and-output-serializers-in-aspnet-core/), you could use custom input formatters with a specific content-type header on the request itself.

First you need to create an input formatter for the overrided version

```
public class MyNonDefaultJsonFormatter : InputFormatter
{
  public MyNonDefaultJsonFormatter()
  {
    this.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear()
    this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/non-default-json");
  }

  public override bool CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
  {
    return base.CanRead(context);
  }

  public override Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext)
  {
    //Do some custom deserializing on context.HttpContext.Request.Body
  }
}
```

Then you need to register the input formatter in configure services

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
  options.InputFormatters.Add(new MyNonDefaultJsonFormatter());
}
```

Then specify the Content-Type as "application/non-default-json" when making your request.

As another idea, you may be able to remove the default JSON deserializer all together and instead register two serializers of your own, both accepting standard application/json, but with type checking in the CanReadType override that allows you to differentiate. I haven''t had a chance to test this out myself, but if I do will report back here.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think I can use InputFormatter as it is part of .Net Core

Comment: Take a look [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/mar/09/using-an-alternate-json-serializer-in-aspnet-web-api) for an example on how you could use a similar concept in Asp.Net. Instead of InputFormatter you can make a custom MediaTypeFormatter, which looks nearly identical. Then register it with 

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new CustomFormatter());`

 Note the insert is used to put this before the built in formatters. If you don;t care about order of resolution Add could be used.

Comment: Yes thanks, using MediaTypeFormatter and specifying the version on the content-type header works. Ideally I would want to be able to have the version in the url not the header

Comment: Glad I could help. If this was what worked for you you can go ahead and mark it as an answer. As far as basing the version off the URL, I'm not sure there is a way to do that without handling your deserilization logic manually. What's the difference in how you want the two deserialized?

Comment: So the final solution to pull the version from the URL was to use a combination of a MediaTypeFormatter and DelegatingHandler. The custom DelegatingHandler would pull the version from the URL and inject it into a custom internal header. Then implementing the MediaTypeFormatter the header could be picked up from the HttpContent in the ReadFromStreamAsync function. Thanks for the help!